# CSV Flat Data processing with performance

Tags: c#, csv

I need some ideas how to increase performance to read from CSV file.

I made one version is working well, but performance is no longer desirable when we have more than 200 000 line per CSV, the processing time is taking a lot of time, and the importing process is going to be very slow in performance.

I will show a little piece of CSV file:

```
"Oliver Russi,oliverrussi31@somecompany1.com,John Brown,VIVW8562,BankName8,72368997,581349,AUD"
"Oliver Russi,oliverrussi31@somecompany1.com,John Brown,VIVW8562,BankName3,77960361,402376,EUR"
"Oliver Russi,oliverrussi31@somecompany1.com,John Brown,VIVW8562,BankName5,73992264,302171,AUD"
"Oliver Russi,oliverrussi31@somecompany1.com,John Brown,VIVW8562,BankName1,00748228,313303,GBP"
"Oliver Russi,oliverrussi31@somecompany1.com,Alberto John,XIWVW8623,BankName8,32368997,381349,AUD"
"Oliver Russi,oliverrussi31@somecompany1.com,Alberto John,XIWVW8623,BankName3,56960361,602376,EUR"

                                                
"Sale agent 1,sale_agent1@somecompany3831.com,Client Name 1 of Sale Agent 1,VIVW8562, BankName8,72368997,581349,AUD"
"Sale agent 1,sale_agent1@somecompany3831.com, Client Name 1 of Sale Agent 1, VIVW8562,BankName3,77960361,402376,EUR"
"Sale agent 1,sale_agent1@somecompany3831.com, Client Name 1 of Sale Agent 1, VIVW8562,BankName5,73992264,302171,AUD"
"Sale agent 1,sale_agent1@somecompany3831.com, Client Name 2 of Sale Agent 1, XIWVW8623, BankName8,32368997,381349,AUD"
"Sale agent 1,sale_agent1@somecompany3831.com, Client Name 2 of Sale Agent 1, XIWVW8623, BankName3,56960361,602376,EUR"
"Sale agent 1,sale_agent1@somecompany3831.com, Client Name 2 of Sale Agent 1, XIWVW8623, BankName5,88992264,702171,AUD"
"Sale agent 1,sale_agent1@somecompany3831.com, Client Name 2 of Sale Agent 1, XIWVW8623, BankName1,97748228,913303,GBP"                             
"Sale agent 1,sale_agent1@somecompany3831.com, Client Name 2 of Sale Agent 1, XIWVW8623, BankName2,44648228,223334,EUR"                             
"Sale agent 2,sale_agent2@somecompany382.com, Client Name 1 of Sale agent 2, VIVW8562, BankName8,72368997,581349,AUD"
"Sale agent 2,sale_agent2@somecompany382.com, Client Name 1 of Sale agent 2, VIVW8562, BankName3,77960361,402376,EUR"
"Sale agent 2,sale_agent2@somecompany382.com, Client Name 1 of Sale agent 2, VIVW8562, BankName5,73992264,302171,AUD"
"Sale agent 2,sale_agent2@somecompany382.com,Client Name 2 of Sale agent 2, XIWVW8623, BankName8,32368997,381349,AUD"
```

---

The desirable output required, based on the CSV piece it is:
List of sale Agents composed of 3 sales agents,
each of one has a list composed with 2 clients and respective client has a list of bank accounts.

Something like next:

```
  "Oliver Russi,oliverrussi31@somecompany1.com,
                John Brown, VIVW8562, 
                        BankName8,72368997,581349,AUD"
                        BankName3,77960361,402376,EUR"
                        BankName5,73992264,302171,AUD"
                        BankName1,00748228,313303,GBP"
  
  "Oliver Russi,oliverrussi31@somecompany1.com,
                Alberto John, XIWVW8623, 
                        BankName8,32368997,381349,AUD"
                        BankName3,56960361,602376,EUR"
                                                        
  "Sale agent 1,sale_agent1@somecompany3831.com,
                Client Name 1 of Sale Agent 1, VIVW8562, 
                        BankName8,72368997,581349,AUD"
                        BankName3,77960361,402376,EUR"
                        BankName5,73992264,302171,AUD"
  
  "Sale agent 1,sale_agent1@somecompany3831.com,
                Client Name 2 of Sale Agent 1, XIWVW8623, 
                        BankName8,32368997,381349,AUD"
                        BankName3,56960361,602376,EUR"
                        BankName5,88992264,702171,AUD"
                        BankName1,97748228,913303,GBP"                              
                        BankName2,44648228,223334,EUR"                              

  "Sale agent 2,sale_agent2@somecompany382.com,
                Client Name 1 of Sale agent 2, VIVW8562, 
                        BankName8,72368997,581349,AUD"
                        BankName3,77960361,402376,EUR"
                        BankName5,73992264,302171,AUD"
  
  "Sale agent 2,sale_agent2@somecompany382.com,
                Client Name 2 of Sale agent 2, XIWVW8623, 
                        BankName8,32368997,381349,AUD"
```

My new improved code using dictionary it is next:

```
public SalesAgentList ToSalesAgentList(string fileName)
        {
            List<SalesAgent> lst_salesAgent = new List<SalesAgent>();
            SalesAgentList salesAgentList = new SalesAgentList(lst_salesAgent);

            try
            {
                lst_salesAgents.Clear();

                string skipStr = "SalesAgentName,SalesAgentEmailAddress,ClientName,ClientIdentifier,BankName,AccountNumber,SortCode,Currency";

                string[] fileContents = File.ReadAllLines(fileName, Encoding.UTF8);

                List<string> lst = fileContents.OfType<string>().ToList().Select(s => s.Replace("\"", string.Empty)).ToList();

                lst.Remove(skipStr);

                ICollection<List<string>> t = (from i in (lst.Select(item => item.Split(',')))
                                               select new List<string> { i[0], i[1], i[2], i[3], i[4], i[5], i[6], i[7] }).Distinct().ToList();

                Dictionary<string, BankAccount> dct_clBancAccount = new Dictionary<string, BankAccount>();

                Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, BankAccount>> clDictionary = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, BankAccount>>();

                Dictionary<string, /*SaleAgent dictionary*/
                        Dictionary<string,/*Client dictionary*/
                                 Dictionary<string, BankAccount>/*Bank Account dictionary*/
                                  >
                          > tmp = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, BankAccount>>>();

                foreach (List<string> itm in t)
                {
                    Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, BankAccount>> tmp_clDictionary = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, BankAccount>>();
                    Dictionary<string, BankAccount> tmp_dct_clBancAccount = new Dictionary<string, BankAccount>();

                    BankAccount clBankAccount = new BankAccount(itm[3], itm[4], itm[5], itm[6], itm[7]);

                    SalesAgentBuilder tmpSaleAgent = new SalesAgentBuilder();
                    tmpSaleAgent.SalesAgentName = itm[0];
                    tmpSaleAgent.SalesAgentEmailAddress = itm[1];

                    if (!tmp.ContainsKey(itm[0]))
                    {
                        dct_clBancAccount.Add(itm[5], clBankAccount);
                        tmp_dct_clBancAccount.Add(itm[5], clBankAccount);
                        tmp_clDictionary.Add(itm[3], tmp_dct_clBancAccount);
                        clDictionary.Add(itm[3], tmp_dct_clBancAccount);
                        tmp.Add(itm[0], tmp_clDictionary);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if (!dct_clBancAccount.ContainsKey(itm[5]))
                        {
                            Dictionary<string, BankAccount> tmpclBnkAccDictionary;
                            if (clDictionary.TryGetValue(itm[3], out tmpclBnkAccDictionary))
                            {
                                tmpclBnkAccDictionary.Add(itm[5], clBankAccount);
                                tmp_dct_clBancAccount.Add(itm[5], clBankAccount);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }


//need to implement salesAgentList = tmp.ToList(); 

            }

            catch (Exception ex) { Console.WriteLine(ex.Message); }
            return salesAgentList;
        }
```

the issue:
I have tryed to change the part of code of foreach to parralel.foreach() but i'm  getting next error.
Just for mention on the normal foreach way it's not getting error.

```
System.NullReferenceException
  HResult=0x80004003
  Message=Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
  Source=mscorlib
  StackTrace:
   at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.Insert(TKey key, TValue value, Boolean add)
   at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.Add(TKey key, TValue value)
   at SalesAgentFileRecordList.<>c__DisplayClass23_0.<ToSalesAgentList>b__3(List`1 itm)
   in D:\doc\GH\DevTest-Q3_v\ProcessCSV.cs:line 1139
```

any help it's appreciated.
thanks,

Comment: which line is giving error?

Comment: Don't reinvent the wheel and use one of the [existing CSV parsing libraries](https://www.google.com/search?q=c%23+csv+parser).

Comment: the next line:tmp.Add(itm[0], tmp_clDictionary);

Comment: Do not try to just add Parallel.For without a good understanding about threadsafety. Have you done any profiling to see what part takes time?

Comment: How long does File.ReadAllLines take with 200,000 line file?

Comment: JonasH, I published the new improved code, not the old one. The old code was 3.5 slower compared to the newer one, since processing was done line by line and used a different class structure. I know it can be improved more if you use a dictionary with parallel processing, at least it will be 7 times faster than the old code.

Comment: Tony Hopkinson, the challenge is to improve the old code to be at least 5x faster, now the old processing is taking about "00: 00: 00.9159989". with my new code, if I don't use parallel processing, the new improved code is 3.5 times faster than the old processing.

Comment: Tony Hopkinson, I checked out the ReadAllLines method, which is the fastest way to read a csv file.

Comment: @GheorgheGraur It's the fastest way to read the entire thing in one go yes, but you don't need to do that. Optimisation is more art than science.

Comment: @TonyHopkinson, that true. thanks for supporting